# Asking users how did you hear about us - influenced my marketing

Tags: usability, navigation

This is a step that has been influenced by marketing people.
The step is now in the middle of the user's task, interrupting them from getting a service quote straight away.

Now, because I'm trying to find the best solution both for UX and marketing, I'm trying to understand where else can I add this step?
The user flow is the following at the moment:
The user selects the type of service and items to be delivered - how did you hear from us screen - price screen and then finally checkout.

Comment: Does it have to be in that exact order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright,

- The user has a certain expectation of the flow which they would have learned from other applications over time.
- Most consumer websites with a checkout flow have the following flow "browse > add to cart > review > checkout"
- So this would also be the expectation of your user
- Seeing a survey question before review would be an outcome your user wouldn't expect
- This would lead to an "expectation-outcome mismatch", which fundamentally hampers user's experience

Hence, do make sure the survey questions are pushed to the end of the flow after the checkout. If the user wants to give this info, they will. If not, then shoving it on their face before checkout would only irritate them. Big UX NO-NO!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below flow:

1. User selects the type of service and items to be delivered
2. Price screen
3. Checkout
4. Order processing spinner with a quick (and optional) survey

You may also try placing the survey at other intermediate steps that require user to wait for some time and later do an analysis on the **participation ratio** for each of the survey placements.